# SQL join return all rows (in either table or both) on condition

Tags: mysql, join, compare

I have a table with a column categorizing the content :

```
id  lang   string
1   EN     text1_en
1   DE     text1_de
1   FR     text1_fr
2   EN     text2_en
2   DE     text2_de
3   DE     text3_de
3   FR     text3_fr
```

I want to obtain a result as such:

```
id  lang  string     id  lang  string    id  lang  string
1   EN    text1_en   1   DE    text1_de  1   FR    text1_fr
2   EN    text2_en   2   DE    text2_de  NULL NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL       3   DE    text3_de  3   FR    text3_fr
```

I tried at first a join:

```
select 
  c1.id,c1.lang,c1.string,
  c2.id,c2.lang,c2.string,
  c3.id,c3.lang,c3.string
from 
  mytable c1
  left join mytable c2 on (c1.id=c2.id and c2.lang='DE')
  left join mytable c3 on (c1.id=c3.id and c3.lang='FR')
where
  c1.lang='EN'
order by c1.id
```

However I get only results for id's 1 and 2.

If I move the `c1.lang='EN'` to the `on` condition, I get all table rows for the first 3 columns (not only `lang='EN'`)

Comment: I tried `where c1.lang not in ('DE','FR')` and `where c1.lang is null or c1.lang='EN'` but I still don't obtain the third row as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use full outer join in servers other than mysql. This query will take some time for large tables.

```
  select 
      c1.id,c1.lang,c1.string,
      c2.id,c2.lang,c2.string,
      c3.id,c3.lang,c3.string
    from 
      mytable c1 left  join mytable c2 on (c1.id=c2.id and c2.lang='DE')   
      left join mytable c3 on (c1.id=c3.id and c3.lang='FR')  
    where
      c1.lang='EN'

    UNION ALL 

    select 
      c1.id,c1.lang,c1.string,
      c2.id,c2.lang,c2.string,
      c3.id,c3.lang,c3.string
    from 
      mytable c2 left  join mytable c1 on (c2.id=c1.id and c1.lang='EN')   
      left join mytable c3 on (c2.id=c3.id and c3.lang='FR')  
    where
      c2.lang='DE'

    UNION ALL 
    select 
      c1.id,c1.lang,c1.string,
      c2.id,c2.lang,c2.string,
      c3.id,c3.lang,c3.string
    from 
      mytable c3 left  join mytable c1 on (c3.id=c1.id and c1.lang='EN')   
      left join mytable c2 on (c3.id=c2.id and c2.lang='DE')  
    where
      c3.lang='FR'
```

Comment: Thank you, however my data is on MySQL.

Comment: Then you have to use union or union all to simulate full outer join.

Comment: `UNION` and not `UNION ALL` did it. Thank you!

Comment: glad it helped, close your question.

Comment: I would close it, but there is no UI to allow me to do that. 
All topics I found about this don't seem to apply properly.